# In SAS, are assigned variables always set to missing before each iteration?

Tags: sas

I am confused as to why this code works and I'm afraid that this is due to misunderstanding of how SAS processes datasets. I thought that the PDV is initialized to missing each iteration for variables created in an assignment statement, while all other variableare overwritten with each iteration. So, I expected Promotion to be missing with the second iteration because there is no RETAIN statement. When is a RETAIN statement needed and why is it not needed here?

```
DATA work.extended;
    SET Orion.Discount;
    WHERE Month(Start_Date)=7 OR Month(End_Date)=7;
    DROP Unit_Sales_Price;
    Promotion="Happy Holidays";
    Season="Winter";
    Output;
    Season="Summer";
    Output;
    RUN;
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
Obs Product_ID Start_Date End_Date Discount Promotion Season
1 210100100038 01JUL2007 31JUL2007 60% Happy Holidays Winter
2 210100100038 01JUL2007 31JUL2007 60% Happy Holidays Summer
3 210200100010 01JUL2007 31JUL2007 60% Happy Holidays Winter
4 210200100010 01JUL2007 31JUL2007 60% Happy Holidays Summer
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're incorrectly defining `iteration`.  One iteration of the data step is not one `output`, but one time from `data` to `run` (or `return`, which `run` has implied).  `Output` has no relation to data step iterations, other than the implied `output` when it is not included.

I suggest the data step debugger (such as [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/btu/25p052.pdf) ) if you want to see this in action.